# Define " as a shortcut

Tags: python, scripting, text-editor

Is it possible to attribute a shortcut has a symbol as the inverted comma or square bracket ?

I edit to give a little more information.
I created an operator who write me directly in the text éditor `""`
and which places me the cursor directly between both.
I'd like to attribute the `"` as shortcut to this operator.

Comment: It's a bit complicated because of different keyboard layouts and how Blender processes input events. `"` on an US keyboard is apparently `Shift+'` (single quote, which is `Ä` on my German keyboard). The value Blender uses for this key (`event.type)` is `QUOTE` (and `event.shift = True`). Double quote on a German keyboard however is `Shift+2`, so a different key, The `event.type` for the `2` key is simply `2`.

Comment: That you for your answer. I remembered an answer that you had given with a script here: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8796/custom-modal-operator-event-timing. By using it, it shall seem that I just need to put 'THREE' for the even type. I use en french keybord ;)

Comment: The problem is that a model operator needs to be running in the background to capture Unicode = `"` input. You can't create a key binding in this way.