# Draw handler only updates when moving the mouse

Tags: python, scripting

I am writing a simple add-on to move the 3D Cursor. It works with a modal operator, the 3D locations follows the mouse position, but it gets the input from the keyboard if the user wants to type a specific dimension. I created a draw handler to show the keyboard input during the modal. It's working, if I press the keyboard number it stores the numbers as it should, but it doesn't show anything until I move the mouse. I would like it to show the numbers as I pressed them on the keyboard. Is there any way I can achieve that?

Comment: See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8796/custom-modal-operator-event-timing  re using `tag_redraw` to tag a redraw. May also be of interest https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/161773/15543

Comment: Have updated the first link above to work in 2.9.  Suggest it could be marked as a duplicate.  Thoughts?

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I flagged as duplicate.